# Mathematically denote an empty string

Tags: computer-science

My background is computer science and im trying to properly document some of my code.

I have a list of strings and I want to mathematically denote a check if the string is empty. The string exists, it might just be empty. Here $S$ is my string and $l$ my list.

I dont think i can denote it as ***if $ S \notin \emptyset$ then*** because an empty string is still a string? quoting wiki `empty string`

```
The empty string should not be confused with the empty language ∅, which is a formal language (i.e. a set of strings) that contains no strings, not even the empty string
```

Or is it as simple as ***if $|S| = 0$ then***

The wiki also mentions `the empty string is denoted with ε or sometimes Λ or λ.` I assume that ***if $S = \epsilon$ then*** is not correct.

Comment: Assuming $|\cdot |$ is in reference to the length of the string, then "if $|S|=0$..." is fine.  Alternatively, using whatever notation for the empty string you like "if $S=\varepsilon$ (where $\varepsilon$ is the empty string)..." is fine too.  *Words* are fine as well, just saying "if $S$ is the empty string..."

Comment: Since you are documenting code specifically... I would refer to it as it is in whatever language you are coding... E.g. for Java, `if (myString.isEmpty())` or in JavaScript, `if (myString === "")`

Comment: @JMoravitz i prefer to document pseudo code so its not language bound

Comment: In which case, use a sufficiently "pseudo-codey" way of writing it...   `if myString is empty` seems perfectly acceptable, readable, and non-ambiguous to me

Answer (score 1):

$\epsilon$ is a property of languages. This is more computer science theory rather than programming. You'll never see $\epsilon$ used in programming.

That being said, I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but there **isn't a need to comment out simple stuff like this**

For example, if you are using Python:

```
if (x):
    print("X is not empty")
```

In python or most languages, to denote a string is empty, you may declare it as such:

```
x = ""
```

This tells you two things.

a) It is a string since it is surrounded by quotes

b) The string is of length 0 since there is nothing between the quotes

There is no need to comment stuff like this. Anyone with a CS background would be able to understand what you are doing here.